# automatically get the name vectors saved in the workspace in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have multiple vectors (+100) that have been  loaded into  MATLAB workspace, I would like to write a script that can plot and save them all, but for that I need their name, my question is: is there a way to automatically get the name  vectors saved in the workspace.

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have 100+ separate variables, you should really go back and look at loading them in a different way (cell arrays, structs, etc). You're only making more pain for yourself down the road.

Comment: it's only one file !

Comment: I don't understand what that means. You have one file - so why do you have 100+ vectors? Where do the names come from?

Comment: it's one file "all.mat" there only one way to load it, and in the file are +100 vector saved !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one: whoever gave you a *.mat file with 100+ named variables in it, [censored for strong language and scenes some viewers may find upsetting].  I am only partly joking here; if you find yourself in this sort of situation normally it is because something has gone terribly wrong upstream.  We can work around it, though.

Step two: use `who` with the filename to get a list of variables in that file

```
names = who('-file', 'all');
```

Step three: load the variables (or a subset of them) into a struct

```
data = load('all.mat');
```

Step four: use dynamic structure naming to extract data:

```
for n = 1:length(names);
   plot(data.(names{n})); % or whatever you want to do with this data
end
```

I would probably just use the loop to dump the data in a cell array so as to make further processing simpler and avoid further use of dynamic field names or worse, `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [who](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/who.html), which lists all variables alphabetically in the active workspace.

Comment: who gives me everything back !

Comment: @Engine Indeed, and after you have everything, you can loop through everything, decide which are (relevant) vectors, and process them.